# How to encode an array of data and save to a pivot table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

All I want here is to be able to save all the ID's of services into the pivot table associated with the given keywords/tags but at the moment all it does is that it takes the last ID of the created object and saves into the pivot table with different keywords. let's say for example I enter [id1 => service1, id2 => service2] and [id1 = > keyword1, id2 => keyword2, id3 => keyword3] instead of it saving only id2 of service2 and all the keywords I want it to save all the Ids of all of the services and the keywords. I hope it makes sense

```
foreach($params['service'] as $key => $value){
      $service = Service::firstOrNew(['service' => $value, 'price' => $params['price'][$key], 'business_id' => $params['business_id']]);
      $service->service = $value;
      $service->price = $params['price'][$key]; 
      $service->business_id = $params['business_id'];
      $service->save();
    }

    foreach($params['keywords'] as $keyword){
      $cleaned_keyword = self::cleanKeywords($keyword); 
      $newKeyword = Keyword::firstOrNew(['keyword' => $cleaned_keyword]);
      $newKeyword->keyword = $cleaned_keyword;
      $newKeyword->save();
      $service->keywords()->syncWithoutDetaching([$newKeyword->id => ['business_id' => $params['business_id']]]);
  }
```

[image: none]

This is something I would expect but it is tricky because a single or 2 services for example can have multiple keywords. NOTE: I had manually changed these values in the database
[image]

These are the results from a dd($params)

[image]

Based on the dd($params).attached is the result,only

```
"service" => array:2[
1 => "Mobile development"
]
```

was saved in the pivot table and got assigned all the keywords

[image]

Comment: What would be the expected result (in the pivot table) of the example data in your question?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, please check the image I have just attached.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($params);` in this case?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, please check newly attached image.

Comment: So "Social media marketing" wouldn't be attached to any service because is there no third entry in `$params['service']`?

Comment: It would but because there's multiple
 services "service" => array:2[
0 => "Web development"
]

won't be saved in the pivot table only

"service" => array:2[
1 => "Mobile development"
]

will be which will have all 3 keywords

Comment: So the screenshot with the expected result is incomplete?

Comment: Yes it is, please see attached image

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if this is a good approach, I managed to solve this by having an inner loop.

```
    foreach($params['service'] as $key => $value) {
    $service = Service::firstOrNew(['service' => $value, 'price' => $params['price'][$key], 'business_id' => $params['business_id']]);
    $service->service = $value;
    $service->price = $params['price'][$key];
    $service->business_id = $params['business_id'];
    $service->save();
    foreach($params['keywords'] as $keyword) {
        $cleaned_keyword = self::cleanKeywords($keyword);
        $newKeyword = Keyword::firstOrNew(['keyword' => $cleaned_keyword]);
        $newKeyword->keyword = $cleaned_keyword;
        $newKeyword->save();
        $service->keywords()->syncWithoutDetaching([$newKeyword->id => ['business_id' => $params['business_id']]]);
    }
}
```

[image]